# Loopback with ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, loopbackjs

I have examined and practiced on creating Rest Api's with loopback and ExpressJS seperately

While Using [Loopback](http://loopback.io/);

1. It was really time consuming to read all the documentation and       learning loopback specific stuff
2. It also enables you to create your Api in a short period of time    and has lots of magic things inside it.
3. I saw that if I face problems while developing with loopback. I    usually get stuck in finding answers from community.

While Using [ExpressJs](http://expressjs.com/)

1. You write almost every api endpoint in same format with lots of copied code.
2. You are comfortable with it and can do anything with ease. 
      But time consuming if compared with loopback.

My point is to utilize best parts of both ExpressJs and Loopback

So my question is "Does it make sense to use [Loopback](http://loopback.io/) with [ExpressJs](http://expressjs.com/) and also use [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/)?"

Related with my question Loopback has a documentation about adding ExpressJS route in Loopback application. [Loopback with Express Route](http://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Add-a-custom-Express-route.html)

If it makes sense is there any recommendation for folder structuring ?

Comment: For you information, Loopback already run on top of Express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As ***@Jspdown*** wrote in his [comment to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911029/loopback-with-expressjs#comment71003617_41911029) Loopback is really based on Express, so you don't need to make choice between them.

When you work on your application using Express and produce 'lots of copied code', soon you start to optimize it and in fact develop your own framework. So this is exactly what Loopback team already have done for you.

Thus the choice is not Loopback or Express but it is - to invest into study ready-made framework or to develop your own framework. As for me I think that if you are working on relatively simple projects and/or quick prototypes or going to change your programming tools soon - don't study, just do. But if you are working on large, mission critical system in long-lasting project - Loopback is helpful.